# Zookeeper no such file or directory

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am trying to install the zookeeper in my laptop. Using the file, which is `bin.tar.gz` 3.6.1 version.https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.6.1/apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin.tar.gz

Following the instructions which are:

1. make a folder `logs` in the main folder.
2. change the file name in `conf` folder, from `Zoo_sample.cfg` to `zoo.cfg`
3. change the `dataDir` path inside the `zoo.cfg` to where the `logs` situated.
4. put the bin path to the environment variables following the post here:https://medium.com/@shaaslam/installing-apache-zookeeper-on-windows-45eda303e835

Using Windows 10 with Bash, the feedback:

```
alex0@DESKTOP-AGJ32D1 MINGW64 /c/Tools/apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin/bin
$ ./zkServer.sh
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: C:\Tools\apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin\conf\zoo.cfg
grep: C:\Tools\apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin\conf\zoo.cfg: No such file or directory
grep: C:\Tools\apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin\conf\zoo.cfg: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
Usage: ./zkServer.sh [--config <conf-dir>] {start|start-foreground|stop|version|restart|status|print-cmd}
```

I am sure that the name of `cfg` file is properly changed, and the dataDir path is set as well. What could the problem I've made? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. It is simply the file name issue.
When I changed it into `zoo.cfg`, the name of the file is `zoo.cfg`. Therefore, just change it to `zoo` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

when you setup zookeeper for the first time at your linux system, the default configuration file that have been created is `zoo_sample.cfg` then when your run the server or the `zkServer.sh` file, the file came by default to check on the config file named as `zoo.cfg`, so there the source of the issue.
[zookeeper config dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otIXv.png)

in my case what I did is that I renamed the file in the zookeeper dir from `zoo_simple.cfg` to `zoo.cfg` by using the following command on terminal.

```
~$ mv zoo_sample.cfg zoo.cfg
```

in case you still facing an error of zookeeper failed to start [as you see in this error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9V48.png)
Try to run Zookeeper with the config file full path, here's the command:

```
~$ sudo ./zkServer.sh start /[path_to_zookeeper_config_dir]/zoo.cfg
```

then the server will start